# Julia macro expansion inside function

Tags: macros, julia

I have a macro that looks like this

```
macro multishift(L...)
    ex = :(0)
    for d in L
        ex =  :($ex | 1 << Int32($d))
    end
    return ex
end
```

So `@multishift(1,2)` will expand out to `0 | 1 << Int32(1) | 1 << Int32(2)`.  Now I add a function like so, and call it:

```
f(L...) = @multishift(L...)
println(f(1,2))
```

This won't work.  I'll get an error that L is not defined.  I can see what is happening here - the macro is being expanded out with L instead of the tuple (1,2).

What is the correct way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could interpolate into `@eval`:

```
julia> f(L...) = @eval @multishift($(L...))
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1,2)
6

julia> a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
(1, 2, 3)

julia> f(a, b, c)
14
```

But that doesn't feel right.  You lose all powers of it being a macro: instead of expanding once at compile time, it expands every time it's called.  With the given function, you should test whether there's much gained at all by using a macro.

Comment: OK, make sense.  Since `@multishift` doesn't know what `L` contains until `f(L...)` is called and compiled.  Once it is, the macro can be expanded.  This is not real code, just playing around with macros in Julia.

Comment: If you're playing around, this would, I think, be a good exercise for a [generated function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/#Generated-functions-1) taking an `Varargs{N, Int}`.